# Конвертирование не стандартного времени в php

Tags: php

Есть переменная

```
$oldtime = "20.04.2020, 18:44";
```

Нужно сконвертировать в datatime для mysql в вид:

```
$newtime = "2020-04-20 18:44:00";
```

Есть ли простое решение?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл:

```
$newtime = date("Y-m-d H:m:s",strtotime($oldtime));
```